# Confusion in identification of quasicoherent sheaves on BG and G -representations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, quasi-coherent-modules

I asked this question on MSE a few days ago, but didn't get a response and also managed to confuse a senior colleague with it since then. This is probably a stupid question, so please bear with me.

Let $k$ be some field, say of characteristic 0, and let $G$ be a finite group considered as a discrete algebraic group. Then we get the classifying Deligne-Mumford stack $BG$ and its etale presentation $p: \mathrm{Spec}\ k\to BG$. We also have the structure map $\pi: BG\to \mathrm{Spec}\ k.$

It is possible to identify quasicoherent sheaves on $BG$ with $k$-linear representations of $G$. To be honest, I don't completely understand this yet, but the gist is (correct me if I'm wrong) that quasicoherent sheaves over various stacks form a stack themselves, and the descent data needed to descend a sheaf over $\mathrm{Spec}\ k$, which is uniquely defined by its vector space of sections, to $BG$ is precisely the data of a $G$-action.

What I'm completely missing is how under this identification we have $\pi_*(V)=V^G,$ where $V$ is a $G$-representation considered as a sheaf on $BG$. The functor $\pi_*$ should be the same as the global section functor, so we have to show that $\Gamma(BG,V)=V^G.$ We have a cartesian square

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G @>s>> \mathrm{Spec}\ k\\
@V t V V @VV p V\\
\mathrm{Spec}\ k @>>p> BG
\end{CD}
The sections over $\mathrm{Spec}\ k$ is just $V$, the sections over $G$ is $V\times G$, and hence, by definition, the sections over $BG$ should be the equalizer of the maps induced by $s,t$. But aren't $s,t$ the same unique map $G\to \mathrm{Spec}\ k$? Am I missing something 2-categorical?

What also confuses me is that when proving the equivalence of quasicoherent sheaves and $G$-representations I only see the data encoding the group action at the level of the fiber product of three copies of a point over $BG$, so "one level above" the cartesian diagram drawn above.

EDIT: I think I understood where the 2-isomorphism comes in. We also have a 2-morphism $\alpha: p\circ s \Rightarrow p\circ t,$ and we have a cocartesian diagram

\begin{CD}
\Gamma(BG,V) @>\Gamma(BG,p)>> \Gamma(\mathrm{Spec}\ k, V)\\
@V \Gamma(BG,p) V V @VV \Gamma(BG,s) V\\
\Gamma(\mathrm{Spec}\ k, V) @>>\Gamma(BG,t)> \Gamma(G,V).
\end{CD}

If the original diagram was strictly commutative, we would get the description of $\Gamma(BG,V)$ as an equalizer. However, in the 2-categorical situation we should only expect this diagram to commute up to a 2-isomorphism, and this is where I got lost. I think that the correct way to state it is to consider the global sections as discrete categories, and then the 2-isomorphism of the original cartesian diagram gives us an automorphism of $\Gamma(G,V)$ which makes the diagram of sections strictly commutative. Is this reasonable?

Comment: Crossposted from MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764487/confusion-in-identification-of-quasicoherent-sheaves-on-bg-and-g-representat

Comment: Your 2-Cartesian diagram is missing the 2-morphism between the two $1$-morphisms.

Comment: @JasonStarr Yes, and this is precisely what bothers me. The way Alper defines this, the global sections of a sheaf on a stack $X$ is the equalizer of two maps from sections over an etale presentation $U$ to the sections over  the fiber product $R$, and this is just an equalizer in vector spaces. But $R$ is only defined up to a $2$-isomorphism, which I don't see how to include in this diagram for the equalizer. So this definition is probably wrong as written. What is the correct one?

Comment: First of all, the correct definitions go back to Giraud, Grothendieck (and Artin-Mazur if you want to interpret all of this in terms of the simplicial scheme associate to a presentation).  Second, you need to use the next term in the simplicial scheme to define the "global sections": $G\times G$ with its three morphisms to $G$ (which encodes the group operation) and the two maps from $G$ to $G\times G$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So it was indeed just an incorrect definition. Could you please write something up as an answer, even if just a reference to the correct definition?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the definition with the equalizer is fine. Remember that a vector space of sections isn't associated to a scheme but rather to a scheme with an etale morphism to $X$. The two pullback maps $\mathcal F(U) \to \mathcal F(R)$ naturally have target the $\mathcal F(R)$ defined with the morphism $R \to X$ obtained from the two routes around the diagram, and the $2$-isomorphism is used to identify those two copies of $\mathcal F(R)$. Or more easily one can work in the 1-category of (affine) schemes with a morphism to $X$.

Comment: The points in your diagram should be $G$ with the trivial $G$-bundle in the top left, $BG$ with the universal $G$-bundle in the bottom right, and $\operatorname{Spec} k$ with the trivial $G$-bundle elsewhere. Now $s$ is the standard projection $G\to \operatorname{Spec} k$ with the usual isomorphism of trivial $G$-bundles, but $t$ is the standard projection $G\to \operatorname{Spec} k$ with the isomorphism of trivial $G$-bundles multiplied by the universal element of $G$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Sorry for tagging you out of the blue, but I think I found where the 2-morphism comes in. Would you please take a look at the edit?